# New Fields Won't Save

Tags: custom-fields

```
I'm using civicrm 4.7.17 on drupal 7.54.  Logged in with administrator rights.

When I try to add a new field, (admin -> customize data and screen -> custom fields) everything works fine.  I create a new set, no problem, but then when I add a new field to the set, and click on save, it just hangs, loading forever. 

This seems to be a new thing as I've created lots of custom fields before.
```

Any ideas?

Comment: When you go to add a custom field, please right-click the **Add Custom Field** button and select "Open in New Tab".  When you save the custom field, you should get a more informative error. Better still, first enable debugging. Go to **Administer menu > System Settings > Debugging and Error Handling**, select "Yes" to both "Enable Debugging" and "Display Backtrace", and press "Save". Repeat the steps that caused your error, and you'll see much a more detailed error. Please update this question with the expanded error and backtrace - and don't forget to disable debug/backtrace when you're done!

Comment: That would make sense to debug it first.  So when I made a new tab, and tried to save, it had this error, " Sorry but we are not able to provide this at the moment.  id is not a valid integer"

Comment: Added the debugging to the original post

Comment: Glad you worked it out!  For reference - the error you gave is the "debug" info but not the "backtrace".  The debug shows the error - but the backtrace shows where in the code that error takes place.  Both are often necessary to solve a problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, so the civirules 1.2 extension was causing the problem.  The problem is documented a bit here: https://github.com/CiviCooP/org.civicoop.civirules/issues/132

Luckily I hadn't set up at civirules stuff so it was easy to just disable it.  Maybe in the future I'll use an updated version of it.